# How do I redirect URLS with IDs using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to redirect traffic from:

```
example.com/profilepage.php?profileid=123456
```

to

```
example.com/profile-page.php?profileid=123456
```

> **Note:** only difference is the new hyphen

I tried several variations with no luck, including

```
RewriteRule ^/?profilepage.php?profileid=([^/]+)/?$ /profile-page.php?profileid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?profilepage.php?profileid=([^/]+)/$ /profile-page.php?profileid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?profilepage.php?profileid=([^/]+) /profile-page.php?profileid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

As you can see, I'm unsure what to do AFTER the profileid regex stuff

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. You have to explicitly match `QUERY_STRING`

**Problems:**

> **1.** You should match query string with `%{QUERY_STRING}`
>
> **2.** Change your regular expression from this `([^/]+)` to `(\d+)`

**Note:**

> Make sure your matched ID is in `%1` instead of `$1`

You can check this `.htaccess` [here](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^profileid=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^profilepage\.php$ /profile-page.php?profileid=%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: When I do either yours or @Croises method, it redirects but the id variable disappears.  In other words, example.com/profilepage.php?profileid=123456  redirects to example.com/profile-page.php?profileid=  .  Any ideas?

Comment: I was mistaken in first comment. It's doing the same thing as I mentioned in @Croises comment, ie. redirecting but including server path, i.e. it redirects to example.com/home/mysiteusername/public_html/profile-page.php‌​?profileid=123456

Answer (score 1):

No need to test the query string, by default it remains unchanged.
You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profilepage\.php$ profile-page.php [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: This redirects but includes the path in it, like this... example.com/home/mysiteusername/public_html/profile-page.php?profileid=123456  Any ideas?